# Waiting for threads to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# program that calls several function and each of these functions call a method in another DLL. This method creates a new thread to do its work and then returns immediately.

The problem is I need my main program to wait for all the outstanding threads to complete. How can I accomplish this?

I tried googling an answer and all the answers I got said to either use TPL (which I can't because I'm using .NET 3.5) or get a reference to the threads and use `Thread.Join`. But since the threads are being created in another DLL file, which I don't have source code access to, this option is out too.

How can I wait for all my threads to finish?

Comment: Does the other dll give any sort of indication when it's done it's work?  An event or callback etc?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - No, but that would certainly solve my issue if they did!

Comment: @Icemanind so how is anyone supposed to use these? put aside .NET, suppose is C/C++/Binary Code/Else?

Comment: @Amit - Welcome to my world. I'm half tempted to just run dotPeek on it, decompile it and just rewrite it myself with a `Completed` delagate. The example that the developer has for using the DLL is just placing a `Sleep(10000)` at the end. Obviously, I'd like a better solution than this.

Comment: Even `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` can't help because that gets unmanaged threads and the correspondence between them and managed threads is hard. I don't see a way you can do this.

Comment: ugh, not nice.  If that's the example they've given, it may explain the lack of events etc...

Comment: @Icemanind, Are you able to get the unmanaged thread id?

Comment: Your process won't exit before all thread are terminated.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Your process won't exit before all *foreground* threads are terminated.

Comment: @YacoubMassad [_"An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread"_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JamesThorpe, if he can get the unmanaged thread id, couldn't he use WaitForSingleObject to wait for the thread?

Comment: @YacoubMassad There might not _even be_ an unmanaged thread ID

Comment: @YacoubMassad - It doesn't give me anything. It returns `void` and there are no properties for getting the Thread or the ID.

Comment: What does the library do? It must do something that is interesting to you, so you should check for that result (e.g. is a file created and available)

Comment: I'm just curious why you HAVE to wait..as @ErnodeWeerd is saying the unmanaged calls must be performing some sort of action. What action is it that you are waiting for exactly?

Comment: @DavidCarrigan - I have to wait because my application that I'm using the DLL in is a console application and if I don't wait, the console application just exits and the threads abort without finishing their work. What its doing is writing data into a database.

Comment: Then there maybe a possibility of polling for those database changes (if you have access to it) After you make the unmanaged call poll for the data you just attempted to insert. Once identified you can go on to call your next unmanaged call, poll and repeat.

Comment: To be honest, a library using threaded code that has an example using basically "just wait it out" thread synchronization should be thrown out. If that is the programmers idea of a *good* way to do thread synchronization I would not expect the quality of the code *inside* the library to be any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I posted this answer only because it does what the OP asked for and I didn't take the answer from [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089257/1300910): *there's nothing that you can do*. But I advice to NOT use this in a production environment. Personally I would ditch that library and implement it myself.

This said, as a test I created a class library that holds a method `DoWork` which starts a background thread that runs for 10 seconds:

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(10000)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
}
```

Now, the idea is to compare the running threads before and after the `ThirdParty.DoWork` call. After the call, one (or more) thread-id's will be collected and translated into thread handle(s) by using `OpenThread`. At the end, you can call `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait until the third party background thread has finished doing its work.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint WaitForMultipleObjects(int nCount, IntPtr[] lpHandles, bool bWaitAll, uint dwMilliseconds);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenThread(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    const uint SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000;

    static IntPtr GetThreadHandleById(int threadId)
    {
        return OpenThread(SYNCHRONIZE, false, threadId);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threads = new List<int>();
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
            threads.Add(thread.Id);

        ThirdParty.DoWork();

        var threadHandlesToWaitFor = new List<IntPtr>();
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
            if (!threads.Contains(thread.Id))
                threadHandlesToWaitFor.Add(GetThreadHandleById(thread.Id));

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for {0} thread(s) to finish...", threadHandlesToWaitFor.Count);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(threadHandlesToWaitFor.Count, threadHandlesToWaitFor.ToArray(), true, 0xffffffff);

        foreach (var handle in threadHandlesToWaitFor)
            CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

In essence, we're waiting for an unmanaged thread that seems to run the spawned managed thread. This can break in the future because .NET does not guarantee that every managed thread runs on its own unmanaged thread.

Comment: Omg, this is so nasty that it's funny. I guess it's a valid last resort solution if you don't need absolute reliability. You never control all the threads running in your process. Others might spawn that you don't understand.

Comment: I also think that, considering it is a console application and one doesn't start using WCF, OWIN or other fancy things, this will be reliable.

Comment: @usr added a disclaimer to warn the crazy folks out here :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can install a custom CLR Profiler. That gives you access to all managed threads. You should be able to intercept pretty much anything. You should be able to intercept thread starts and shutdown.

The CLR Profiler API is used by hosts such as SQL Server and ASP.NET to perform extremely invasive monitoring and behavior changes to .NET code being hosted.

As a last resort you can even use the Profiler API to runtime rewrite the IL of that library...

This is a reliable way to do it but probably not easy or quickly done.

Answer (score -1):

Given that the asynchronous method you're calling provides no indication of when its complete (a `Task`, callback, event, etc.) there's nothing for you to do.  You can always refactor a method using one of these approaches into a different one, but if the core method provides no indication of when it's done, then there's nothing that you can do.